# Help Finding an Example to Assumption

Tags: calculus

There are two parts to this problem. **I have already proven** the first part which was to prove that:

If $\text{sup}$ $A$ $<$ $\text{sup}$ $B$, show that there exists a $b\in B$ that is an upper bound for $A$.

The second part (**which I am having trouble with**) is:

Give an example to show that this is not always the case if we only assume $\text{sup} A = \text{sup} B$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $A=[0,1]$ and $B=(0,1)$

Comment: and this would work since the $\text{sup}$ $A = 1$ which is clearly not an element of $B$ since it is an open interval, correct

Comment: Yes, that is correct.